# Swift: Trying to get a button on one cell to be enabled instead of all the buttons on all the cells

Tags: swift, uibutton, uigesturerecognizer

I have a populated collectionView that contains hidden delete buttons at the bottom of all of them and will only appear once the user presses and holds the cell. I'm trying to make it so that when they press and hold a cell, only the cell that they pressed will enable and show the delete button.

```
 func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! homeworkcell
        id = indexPath.item
        cell.delteButton.hidden = true
        cell.delteButton.enabled = false
     // remove swipe gestures
            if cell.gestureRecognizers?.count != nil {
        for recognizer in cell.gestureRecognizers! {
            cell.removeGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
        }
    }

            // add the swipe gestures
              let longPress = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "deleteMode:")
    cell.addGestureRecognizer(longPress)
    cell.tag = indexPath.row


    ... return cell
    }



    func deleteMode(sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
            let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: sender.view!.tag, inSection: 0)

             if let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! homeworkcell! {
            cell.delteButton.hidden = false
            cell.delteButton.enabled = true

        }
            //userDelete = true
            userWantsToRemoveDeleteButton = false
            doneEditingButton.enabled = true

            collectionView.reloadData()

        }
```

However, when I run the program the delete button never shows up, which must mean either I'm getting the indexPath of the selected cell incorrectly, I declared the cell incorrectly, or something else I'm not aware of. Is there some code I'm missing to specify which cell for the button to appear?

Any help would be appreciated. (Also deleteButton is misspelled as delteButton, sorry).

Comment: Is there a reason why you add the GestureRecognizer to a subview of your cell called collectionView instead of the cell itself?

Comment: @hmSchuller Ahh... I was following an code example and I sort of copied it away without thinking. My bad. I made some changes, but it is still not working.

Comment: Is the deleteMode function ever being called?
Also, your sender in the deleteMode func is a UISwipeGestureRecognizer. Shouldn't it be a UILongPressGestureRecognizer?

Comment: @hmSchuller I actually just figured it out. It was because I had the line `collectionView.reloadData()` at the end of my deleteMode function, and that would always revert my button to being hidden again because at the top of my cellForRowAtIndex function i have `cell.delteButton.hidden = true`  Once I delete that line, it worked.